# I want to implement the hashtable in javascript but it has an exception

Tags: javascript, hashtable

```
function HashTable(){
    var size = 0;
    var entry = new Object();
    this.add = function(key,value){
        if(!containsKey(key)){
            size++;
        }
        entry[key] = value;
    }

    this.getValue = function(key){
        return containsKey(key)?entry[key]:null;
    }

    this.remove = function(key){
        if (containsKey(key) && delete entry[key]) {
            size--;
        }
    }

    this.containsKey = function(key){
        return (key in entry);
    }

    this.containsValue = function(value){
        for(var prop in entry){
            if(entry[prop] == value){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //get all values
        this.getValues = function(){
            var values = new Array();
            for(var prop in entry){
                values.push(entry[prop]);
            }
            return values;
        }
    //get all keys
        this.getKeys = function(){
            var keys = new Array();
            for(var prop in entry){
                values.push(prop);
            }
            return keys;
        }
    this.getSize = function(){
        return size;
    }

    this.clear = function(){
        size = 0;
        entry = new Object;//???????????????????
    }
}

var hashtest = new HashTable();
hashtest.add('name','LiMing');
```

I want to implement the hashtable in javascript but when I test it ,there is an exception like this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: containsKey is not defined
    at HashTable.add (:8:3)
    at :64:10

Comment: Look at Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Thank you very much for you advice sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is an issue of [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). The javascript interpreter does not know you mean the `containsKey` from the HashTable class.

When calling functions within the class scope be sure to reference them with "[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)". So `containsKey` should be referenced as `this.containsKey(key)`. That way the interpreter knows you are referring to the class' scope and not the local scope.

You should also do this for the variables with class scope. So when you do `size++` you should actually write `this.size++`. Same for `entry`. If you do not add "this", it will assume it is a local function or variable defined within that function itself.

So you should rewrite your add() function as

```
this.add = function(key,value){
        if(!this.containsKey(key)){
            this.size++;
        }
        this.entry[key] = value;
    }
```

Why are you manually keeping track of the size anyway? You can simply define "entry" as an array and use this.entry.size

Considering the more specific case of the hashmap, I would advice you to simply create two arrays within the object, one for the keys and one for the values, this will drastically simplify the problem for you because then you can simply use the builtin Javascript array functions. Both arrays will have a numerical index but the key and the value will both always have the same index so you can easily math them up. The result would be like this:

```js
function HashTable() {
  this.keys = new Array();
  this.values = new Array();

  this.add = function(key, value) {

    if (this.containsKey(key)) {
      var index = this.keys.indexOf(key);
      this.values[index] = value;
    } else {
      this.keys.push(key);
      this.values.push(value);
    }
  }

  this.containsKey = function(key) {
    return this.keys.includes(key);
  }

  this.containsValue = function(value) {
    return this.values.includes(value);
  }

  this.get = function(key) {
    var index = this.keys.indexOf(key);
    return this.values[index];
  }

  this.remove = function(key) {
    if (this.containsKey(key)) {
      var index = this.keys.indexOf(key);
      this.keys.splice(index, 1);
      this.values.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  this.size = function() {
    return this.keys.length;
  }

  this.clear = function() {
    this.keys = new Array();
    this.values = new Array();
  }
}

// Create hashtable
var hashTable = new HashTable();

// Add some test data
hashTable.add('name', 'LiMing');
hashTable.add('location', 'At home');
hashTable.add('eyes', 'blue');

// Updates the value, doesn't add it
hashTable.add('eyes', 'brown');
console.log(hashTable.get("eyes"));

// Get the size
console.log(hashTable.size());

// Check if a value or key is in the hashtable
console.log(hashTable.containsValue("test")); // False
console.log(hashTable.containsValue("LiMing")); // True
console.log(hashTable.containsKey("name")); // True
console.log(hashTable.containsKey("age")); // False

// Get all the keys and values
console.log(hashTable.keys);
console.log(hashTable.values);

// Remove an item
hashTable.remove('eyes');
console.log(hashTable.keys);
console.log(hashTable.values);

// Clear hashtable
hashTable.clear();
console.log(hashTable.keys);
console.log(hashTable.values);
```

Comment: If define "entry" as an array ,its key just can be the type of number.
Sorry, my English is poor ,so if the tone is terrible ,please forgive me .

Comment: That's true, Javascript does not support associative arrays (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). 
However I would simply advice you to have 2 arrays in your object, a array with the keys, and another array with the values.

Comment: Your advice is valuable to me！Thanks a lot！

Comment: I included a detailed explanation of the solution in my answer. You can test run it in the snippet. If the answer is satisfactory please mark the question as answered. ;)

Comment: Why are we tring to do here? Navtive map support any primitive, symbol, or enemy object as key, aren't they the ideal solution for hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.containsKey` instead, as `containsKey` is a 'member' method inside the object created by `HashTable`, you have to reference it with `this`.

```js
function HashTable(){
    var size = 0;
    var entry = new Object();
    
    this.containsValue = function(value){
        for(var prop in entry){
            if(entry[prop] == value){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    this.add = function(key,value){
        if(!this.containsKey(key)){
            size++;
        }
        entry[key] = value;
    }

this.getValue = function(key){
    return this.containsKey(key)?entry[key]:null;
}

this.remove = function(key){
    if (this.containsKey(key) && delete entry[key]) {
        size--;
    }
}

this.containsKey = function(key){
    return (key in entry);
}


//get all values
    this.getValues = function(){
        var values = new Array();
        for(var prop in entry){
            values.push(entry[prop]);
        }
        return values;
    }
//get all keys
    this.getKeys = function(){
        var keys = new Array();
        for(var prop in entry){
            values.push(prop);
        }
        return keys;
    }
this.getSize = function(){
    return size;
}

this.clear = function(){
    size = 0;
    entry = new Object;//???????????????????
}
}

var hashtest = new HashTable(); hashtest.add('name','LiMing');
console.log(hashtest.getValues())
```

There's a better way to organize your code using ES6:

```js
class HashTable {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 0;
    this.entry = new Object();
  }
  
  containsValue(value) {
    for(var prop in entry){
      if(this.entry[prop] == value){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  add(key,value) {
    if(!this.containsKey(key)){
      this.size++;
    }
    this.entry[key] = value;
  }
  
  getValue(key) {
    return this.containsKey(key) ? this.entry[key] : null;
  }
  
  remove(key) {
    if (this.containsKey(key) && delete this.entry[key]) {
      size--;
    }
  }
  
  containsKey(key) {
    return (key in this.entry);
  }
  
  //get all values
  getValues() {
    var values = new Array();
    for(var prop in this.entry){
      values.push(this.entry[prop]);
    }
    return values;
  }
  
  //get all keys
  getKeys() {
    var keys = new Array();
    for(var prop in this.entry){
      values.push(prop);
    }
    return keys;
  }
  
  getSize() {
    return this.size;
  }
  
  clear() {
    this.size = 0;
    this.entry = new Object();//???????????????????
  }
  
}


var hashtest = new HashTable(); hashtest.add('name','LiMing');
console.log(hashtest.getValues())
```

Comment: And this.entry and many more, and make a note about native Map implementation.